# My app crashes when the file has played (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

As soon as the file has played, the app crashes and i get this error:

> -[fefef.ViewController lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle(sender as! UIButton)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9883785f40

How can i solve it?

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    musikAfspiller("wwww.myurl.com")
    lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle(sender as! UIButton)
}

func musikAfspiller (url: String) {

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)

    player.play()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle()",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
}

func lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle(sender: UIButton) {

    if counter == 1 {

        counter = 2

        sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {

        counter = 1
        sender.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using iOS simulator? or on actual iPhone? if on iOS simulator, are you running it on Mac Mini?

Comment: define :                          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle:",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)

Comment: Im using both the simulator on a macbook pro and iPhone. The app still crashes.

Comment: write NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle:",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)   instead of   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle()",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)

Answer (score 2):

the syntax for the observer declaration should be:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
```

and the receiving function should be outside the viewDidLoad() function in this syntax:

`func lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle(notification: NSNotification) {}`

Answer (score 1):

The selector declaration should not have the parentheses when you sending the notification use this:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
```

Also the signeture of the function receiving the notification should look like this:

```
func lavEnFunktionDerSkifterTitle(notification: NSNotification)
```

More details about NSNotification can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)